# How to rename a font to be recognized by LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice, fonts

A colleague has sent me a presentation. I noticed that almost all texts flow over the page. The reason was that all texts are in the "DINCondensed-Bold" font, which I did not have.

I found the DIN Condensed font [here](https://www.cufonfonts.com/font/din-pro-cond), downloaded it and installed it, but, when I opened LibreOffice Impress again, I noticed that all texts still overflow, since the font names are different: the font-name in the presentation is called "DINCondensed-Bold" (without space) while my font is called "DIN Condensed" (with a space).

How can I rename the font I downloaded, so that LibreOffice Impress recognizes it as the font in the presentation?

NOTE: for my purposes, I do not need to have the exact same font - all I need is to have a font of the same width so that it does not overflow.

EDIT: The slides were created in KeyNote. I opened the KEY file in Impress and saved as ODP. [Here is the first slide](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2nfxtowp6f6h2ws/first-slide.odp?dl=0).

Comment: was the document also created in LibreOffice?  If it was created in another application this might not be a problem with the font, but a difference between the way two applications handle the same file.  Layouts in particular can be affected by this.  Wherever you installed the DINCondensed font you should be able to just rename the font: navigate to folder `cd /path/to/fontfolder` then `sudo mv oldname.ttf newname.ttf` or you can copy the font to /usr/share/fonts/  `sudo cp /path/to/font.ttf /usr/share/fonts/DINCondensed-Bold.ttf` (note: keep the same file extension - it might not be `ttf`)

Comment: Responding to "was the document also created in LibreOffice?" may help. And if there's nothing private in the file, you could upload it somewhere foe people to look at.

Comment: @Nmath indeed the file was created in another application (keynote). I installed the file by just clicking on it and then clicking "Install". I found in my ~/.local/share/fonts folder, a file named "DINCondensed-Bold.ttf". But still, in LibreOffice it is shown as "DIN Condensed"!

Comment: @DKBose I added a link to the first slide

Comment: I’d try another way: Rename the font reference in the file. If the format is [ODP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument#Specifications), it can be unzipped and the XML sources edited as plain text.

Comment: If you've got that exact font installed, it's probably not the font - and more evidence that it's a difference in the way different applications render the same data.  This sometimes even happens within different versions of the same application on the same operating system.   The only surefire way to avoid that problem is to use a file type like .PDF where fonts/layouts are embedded in the document and appear the same no matter what.  Of course .PDF is not the best format for a presentation.  You may also ask your colleague to try to save the document into a different format--